# How to store and load/display local PDFs with browser-data, from a website

Tags: javascript, pdf, local-storage, html5-filesystem

I'm working with an extremely old database system containing people and associated PDFs. I can access most data over a webbrowser, however PDFs cannot be requested via web-api - I do however have the liberty of loading any javascript library, and use chrome webdev console.

I want to get a proof of principle working, where I can load a person's PDFs. But I'm not quite sure what the best approach is.

1. Idea to upload a file to the website's local storage in my browser (since it's viewed several times). However I seem to be lacking a good library to save/load files from the cache directory. This [library wasn't updated since 2016](https://github.com/klawson88/Baked-Goods/blob/master/bakedGoods.js) and [Filesaver.js](https://github.com/eligrey/FileSaver.js) doens't seem to be keen on loading the files after saving. Using a fully-fledged database implementation seems overkill (most files will be <= 5-10MB)
2. Loading a file from local storage (even if dir is added to workspace in chrome) seems completely impossible, that would've been an alternative
3. adding the local file path to a `<a href="">` element did not work in chrome

**Is there a feasible approach to manage/associate PDF files on my local drive with the website I'm working with (and have full client-side control, i.e. can load any library)?**

Note: Access is restricted, no chrome addons can be used and chrome cannot be started using custom flags

Comment: Remember the `--allow-file-access-from-files` -flag when working with Chrome and local files.

Comment: Can't you run a local webserver where the directory holding the PDF files is accessible? For example, if using Apache, then you would use Directory and Alias directives to define an alias that maps name **pdf_directory** to the physical location on disk of the directory.Then a reference to the local PDF might be, for example, **[http://localhost/pdf_directory/example.pdf](http://localhost/pdf_directory/example.pdf)**.

Comment: oh crap I was away for a couple of days. local webserver not possible. Ideally I want serve/display local PDFs (i.e. downloaded), running on a website that I do not control-server-side. The download is NOT from the displayed website, but from another ('cryogenic system') alltogether. The most straightforward thing I could think of is actually uploading the pdf to the website, and then serving it at later times. I guess I just need the right library for that and an upload field?

Comment: it's an ancient oracle database, curling doens't seem possible?

Answer (score 2):

I don't exactly know what you are asking for, but this code will get all the pdfs in a selected directory and display them and also makes a list of all the file objects. This will only work in a "[secure context](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Secure_Contexts)" and on [chrome](https://caniuse.com/?search=showDirectoryPicker)

(it also wont run in a sandbox like a stackoverflow code snippet)

js

```
let files = [];
async function r() {
  for await (const [_, h] of (await window.showDirectoryPicker()).entries()) files.push(await h.getFile());
  files = files.filter(f => f.type === "application/pdf");
  for (const f of files) {
    let e = document.createElement("embed");
    e.src = URL.createObjectURL(f), e.type = f.type;
    document.body.appendChild(e);
  }
}
```

html

```
<button onclick="r()">read PDFs</button>
```

also you can probably use [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileReader/readAsDataURL) if you need to send the local PDF somewhere

not sure this answers the question but i hope it helps

Comment: window.isSecureContext() returns false on the website that I should display the PDFs, not quite sure how to change that

Answer (score 1):

Since ActiveX controls are no longer available browsers can display a PDF or a user can download the pdf.

For any more control over that I suspect you could try render the pdf using a JavaScript library like https://mozilla.github.io/pdf.js/

For full control you wont be in a position to control the PDF version, you could alternatively render the PDFs to images on the server and display image versions of the pages.